# How to target interests in ads-api

Tags: facebook-ads-api, targeting, adgroup

I'm interested to create an ad which is targeted for "things" that appear in your main like-page at your profile. 
Some Favorite pages are in organized categories, but some are not  - and there's the Like area as well.

For instance, three such objects that can appear on your profile-like-page are:

- facebook.com/FightClub (part of Movies-category, Favorites)
- facebook.com/pages/Avenue-Q/14821403017 (not an original fan-page ; under "Other", Favorites)
- www.facebook.com/misunderstanding.of.things (as Likes)

I have read the specs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/targeting-specs/ , but not sure what is the proper way to treat these three objects in my targeting-request.

I have the desired pages names (and internal facebook-ids, which can be spotted in the page-code itself) and want to build the correct targeting-request (inside the *adgroups*
request).

Based on the spec, i know that:

- Connections seem to be targeted by the object-ids - but for that i need to be the fan-page/app/event owner, so that's not relevant.
- Likes and interests (keywords) should be relevant, but that is targeted by the object-name. The name includes duplicates of other objects with the same name (for instance: facebook.com/pages/Fight-Club/71836058853 facebook.com/pages/Fight-Club/109398569079581 facebook.com/FightClub ; some with the exact name, although different url of course) , which i do not want to target.
- I would assume that the like-pages can also be targeted using their id or full-url, but did not see such option.

What is the correct targeting-approach for specific interests and likes?
(I also consider checking the power-editor source code & capture-sniffs handling with such requests, but i think a technical response will be better)

Thanks,

Srul.

Answer (score 0):

> Connections seem to be targeted by the object-ids - but for that i need to be the fan-page/app/event owner, so that's not relevant.

What do you need the “owner” for?

All you need is the Facebook ID of the page. And all three of the examples you mentioned have one of those, and you can get them without bothering the page owner or having any special rights to these pages.

Comment: It specifically says (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/targeting-specs/):

An array of Facebook IDs. Connections allows you to target your ads to users who have become a fan of your Page, a member of your Group, RSVP’d to your Event or authorized your Application. The session user has to be an admin of the page, group or event, or developer of the application that is being targeted against. Limit: 50 connections.

Comment: OK, I see – I guess that means for _creating_ an ad targeting an FB page, the user creating the add has to be admin. Which kinda makes sense, because otherwise you could try to damage other page’s reputation by placing “malicious” adds.

Comment: Yes, maybe i can see some logic in it, but note that *targeting* a page does not mean creating and ad *for* that page (meaning, referring to the FB-fanpage as part of its campaign), but using the page  as a keyword-trigger for something else (i can still use its name as keyword, and other related triggers) - which should surely be allowed.



Bottom line, is it possible that for generating an ad using a page (as a third-party), i have to use verbal keywords and not specific-id-pages?